# Safari / Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, safari, onload

I dont know where this question actually goes or how to describe it but im going to try.

I have a site which works on all browsers. Now on all browsers when i move my mouse over the window nothing happens (which is correct), though on Safari, when I move my mouse over the window, i get the Page Load event firing (IsPostBack is false).

Anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it? Or even where to start?

I've looked at the headers, which are standard, there is no form data and as far as i can see there are no javascript handlers to cause this action.

---

Seems ive found something, though not an answer
Wehn the first requerst is done, the request header is as follows:

GET http://site/page HTTP/1.1
Host: servername.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko)
 Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: referingurl
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: fontSize=small; ASP.NET_SessionId=vzjti1mpawhery3gn3q2jeb5; 
SSOPD=BhzM0ZnPn4qh2hqbVtN8wJrgaKycxw1tv3ly/pvpinCrBjsmAOulgZZ5ILBq2421kwMysm8MbmmgBtILxGYZ5RMWn+vbeqiaSIgi2GLszt8=
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

After than when i move the mouse over the page i get this:

GET http://site/page HTTP/1.1
Host: servername.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22
Accept: */*
Referer: referingurl
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: fontSize=small; ASP.NET_SessionId=vzjti1mpawhery3gn3q2jeb5; SSOPD=BhzM0ZnPn4qh2hqbVtN8wJrgaKycxw1tv3ly/pvpinCrBjsmAOulgZZ5ILBq2421kwMysm8MbmmgBtILxGYZ5RMWn+vbeqiaSIgi2GLszt8=
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Does this happen if you disable javascript? Any browser plugins that you might have installed?

Comment: Ive done a profile in Safari, and no javascript is executed, but let me test quickly with javascript disabled

Comment: Still fires, event though javascript is disabled.

Comment: if i create a blank page then its fine, it does not do it. So its definitly something pre-existing. Now to try find out where it is comming from.

Comment: Seems ive found something, though not an answer

Comment: Do you have any dynamic menu on your master page ? have a look like this:  http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/10/20/Gotcha-WebKit-(Safari-3-and-Google-Chrome)-Bug-with-ASPNET-AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 0):

VB or C#? If VB, check Handles statement for page load. What does it say?

Also, any InitializeComponent code anywhere?